# Open file on already open application

Tags: command-line, application-development, vlc

I use VLC to open my video files, but every time I double click on a video a new instance of VLC is created. I want that when a VLC is already open, then the new video file should open in that existing player instead of creating a new instance.

Answer (score 2):

Open VLC, go to <kbd>Tools</kbd> in the toolbar and then <kbd>Preferences</kbd>

Then go to the <kbd>Interface</kbd> tab, and look for this:

[image]